# Modifying constant vector in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I had a question on the Pramp platform. The task was to reverse words in a given string(a vector of chars). They expected a solution with no extra space, however the vector passed in the function was a 'const'.

```
vector<char> reverseWords(const vector<char>& arr )
```

So is there a way to modify a const vector? Or is there something that I don't get about const?

Comment: Create a new vector inside of that function and return that as the result. You're obviously not meant to change the original one. The return value requires a copy anyways.

Comment: Ok so what seems to explain it is that you can take extra space but it only counts in the space complexity if you're taking some auxiliary space.

Comment: Explain based on what please? Your requirements constitution is pretty vague, while the function signature tells a a quite clear story. Maybe you focus more about what exactly you didn't understand? Can you change that function signature, was it your choice?

Comment: I suspect there is some confusion regarding _"They expected a solution with no extra space"_.  The function you show here **must** produce a new `std::vector` as its return value.  It is not designed to modify the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a new vector inside the function which uses the values from the const vector, and then returns that.

```
vector<char> reverseWords(const vector<char>& arr )
{
    vector<char> newArr;
    
    // Do stuff with arr and newArr
    ...

    return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can shoot yourself in foot via:

```
auto newVec = const_cast<vector<int>*>(&vec);
```

that means you are breaking your promise.

The right approach here as suggested by the others would be, to make your own copy and modify your copy.